# How to add a message payload using qiscus sdk

Tags: android, json, chat

I developed chat with android qiscus sdk. I have a problem about custom payload message  to implement in QiscusComment.generateCustomMessage().

Anyone can help me ? 
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String message = "Survey Qiscus";
    JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
    try {
        payload.put("sticker_url", "https://res.cloudinary.com/qiscus/image/upload/fxwzBRPcdz/Bubble-Pup-Yup.gif");
        payload.put("profile_url", "http://res.cloudinary.com/diufvqwbr/image/upload/v1507608923/logo_gb4lzy.png");
        payload.put("title_survey", "Qiscus@ Selles Survey");
        payload.put("date", "2017-10-29");
        payload.put("link_url", "https://www.qiscus.com/");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    QiscusComment comment = QiscusComment.generateCustomMessage(message, "survey", payload,
            qiscusChatRoom.getId(), qiscusChatRoom.getLastTopicId());
```

you can send your comment with 
**sendQiscusComment**(comment);

You can using JsonArrays to custom your message payload. I hope its can help you to develop your apps.

Good luck !!